# i'm facing some Error during python manage.py makemigrations in django

Tags: django, sqlite

`Foreign Key mismatch Error`
`Foreign Key Constrain Fail` and many more error related foreign key and constrain

and also delete all the stuff inside a database(Not table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete all the migration files except **init**.py  After that

run  `python manage.py makemigrations`
and
`pyhton manage.py migrate` again